# Lost hard drive capacity after installing ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive, gparted

I recently decided to install ubuntu on my older computer because I hate windows 10, I had nothing important on it so I didn't bother selecting partitions and creating a swap partition, one for / and one for /home or formating the existing ones. So I justed clicked on install over windows 10. The setup process went fine but my hdd went from a capacity of 1To to  just 74 Go!!!!

I tried gparted but the space seem to have disappeared!

I need a little help from you guys to figure it out...

Thanks in advance!

PS: english is not my first language so I hope you understood what I said ^^

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a screenshot of GParted showing that drive's partitions?

Comment: Please do as MichaelBay has said, your HDD certainly went some where!

Comment: Maybe you installed legacy mode over a UEFI GPT and smashed the partition table? Might have to low-level format your HDD again...

Comment: Please provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l -u` and `sudo parted -l` to help troubleshoot the issue.